# Need help optimizing mysql query to get it to sort quickly by index

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Someone helped me come up with this query but its still too slow; The order by is slowing it down and I dont think its using my index
I'm hoping someone can fix it for me :D Yes I read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) page but I can't understand it.

**Query:**

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT u.id, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
 FROM urls u
 JOIN tags t ON t.url_id = u.id
 AND t.tag = 'osx'
 ORDER BY u.numsaves DESC
 LIMIT 20 

 Showing rows 20 - 19 ( 20 total, Query took 1.5395 sec) [numsaves: 6130 - 2107]


 id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE  t   ref     tag_id  tag_id  767     const   49432   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_numsaves_IX  PRIMARY     4   jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t.url_id     1
```

**Database:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `urls` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `url` text NOT NULL,
 `domain` text,
 `title` text NOT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `numsaves` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `firstsaved` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
 `md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
 KEY `id_numsaves_IX` (`id`,`numsaves`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2958560 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

 CREATE TABLE `tags` (
 `url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `tag_id` (`tag`,`url_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I think I crashed sqlfiddle while fiddling with this. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem with your query is your choice of indexes.

1) `tags` has a compound `UNIQUE KEY` on `tag` and `url_id` but no `PRIMARY KEY`.

If nothing else, you should make it primary - this may help a bit with performance. Also, you might want to take a close look if `VARCHAR(255)` is really necessary for your tags. It makes the index quite big.

2) add a separate index on `numsaves` since you're ordering by that. The compound index on `id` and `numsaves` is not going to help here.

3) `EXPLAIN` says that you have 49432 rows in `tags` that match `"osx"`. This is quite redundant. You may want to split your tags table into two, one containing the text while the other contains the N:M link to `urls`.